# AWS EKS The connection to the server ASFASF.da2.ap-northeast-1.eks.amazonaws.com was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks, eksctl

I'm trying to create kubernetes cluster, but whatever mode I try in the end `kubectl` fails with

```
The connection to the server ASFASF.da2.ap-northeast-1.eks.amazonaws.com  was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I already tried:

1) Install with **Terraform** ( following all official docs )
2) **Manual EKS** installation through UI
3) Install with **eksctl** tool

It all ends with this error, I already tried to tweak all possible subnets, roles, users, routes, dns, basically everything what might help in other SA threads / github issues, but no success..

What am I missing?

inb4 yes I tried update kubectl config or specify role there
like here:
https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/issues/1510
https://medium.com/@savvythrough/aws-eks-auth-optimization-for-k8s-ae054be0a31b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**vpn**, turning it *on* might help

I spent lot of time on this issue and it all because some DNS blocks in the area I was connecting from, lol

Answer (score 0):

For me, my endpoint was set to `private=true,public=false`. I changed to `private=true,public=true`. I used terraform so the parameters look like below

```
endpoint_private_access = true
endpoint_public_access  = true
```

More reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cluster-endpoint.html